# Modeling a fish with curves - complication at tail

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, nurbs-surface

I'm modeling a fish with Bézier curves, but now I have a body of rotation and don't know how to carve out the tail.

I have searched Google and YouTube for the problem, but the nearest thing I have found is a tutorial for creating trees, but with this method I don't get a sharp edge between the tails.

Basically, I'd be happy if I could cut away the surplus material at the tail from the body of rotation with the bisect tool. The tail would be angular, so I'd need some bisect too that could cut spherically.

If you have a whole different solution I'd be happy to hear it! Maybe with nurbs-surface-circles or something like that??

I have looked at [this tutorial (in German)](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc%3aDE/2.4/Manual/Modeling/Curves#Oberfl.C3.A4chen_aus_Curves_erzeugen_.5BSkinning.5D), and in that case I would need to align the nurbs-circle-surfaces to a curve. This method (if possible) would be the very best one!

Thanks in advance for helping me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not give sculpting a try? You could make something close to what you want and touch up the details in sculpt...

heres a link to a video instructing how to use dynamic topology (and by extension sculpt mode)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opsKPCCFbr4

docs on sculpting

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Sculpt_Mode

[image]

docs on dynamic topology

(note that this feature has been changed in 2.7, it can now be found under the header labelled "dynotopo")

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.66/Dynamic_Topology_Sculpting

[image]

Comment: Could you add a short description of what you mean? If the link goes down, so does this answer. You can keep the link, but add a summery.

Answer (score 1):

[image: curves, bevel, taper...]

what i basically did here:

1. a curve (the big cylinder) (lets call it curve1)
2. using as bevel object the circle (blue) so that the curve is no longer a curve , but a cylinder (lets call it circle)
3. using another curve (green) as taper object so you can have a cylinder with different thickniss at different points (lets call it curve2)
4. without the ~0,35 at the red marker the arrows at the cylinder would be in the middle of the object... i find it easier this way, for giving the cylinder the right shape, because that  way you can easily set the shape of the bottom with curve1 and the shape of the top with curve2